# Android: error in putting open gl object on camera view

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera

I'm trying to put an object on camera view using open gl, it works good on emulator but when I test it on real android device the camera view or open gl object does not be shown.

this is my MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Our variables 
CameraPreview cv;
GLSurfaceView glView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("index", 0);

    /* Set the screen orientation to landscape, because 
     * the camera preview will be in landscape, and if we 
     * don't do this, then we will get a streached image.*/
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    // requesting to turn the title OFF
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    glView.getHolder().setFormat( PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT );
    glView.setRenderer(new GlRenderer(this, index));
    // Now set this as the main view.
    setContentView( glView  );
    Load();
}

public void Load(){
    // Try to get the camera 
    Camera c = getCameraInstance();        
    // If the camera was received, create the app
    if (c != null){

        // Create a new camera view and add it to the layout
        cv = new CameraPreview(this,c);  
        cv.setZOrderOnTop(false);
        if(glView != null){
            // Set the layout as the apps content view 
            addContentView( cv, new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
        }

    }
    // If the camera was not received, close the app
    else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "Unable to find camera. Closing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }
}

/* This method is strait for the Android API */
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;

    try {
        c = Camera.open();// attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}



/* Override the onPause method so that we 
 * can release the camera when the app is closing.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (cv != null){
        cv.onPause();
        cv = null;
    }
}

/* We call Load in our Resume method, because 
 * the app will close if we call it in onCreate
 */
@Override 
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();


}
}
```

and this is the GlRenderer class

```
public class GlRenderer implements Renderer {

private Square      square;     // the square
private Context     context;
private int imageIndex;

/** Constructor to set the handed over context */
public GlRenderer(Context context, int index) {
    this.context = context;
    imageIndex = index;
    // initialise the square
    this.square = new Square(imageIndex);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // clear Screen and Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Reset the Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    // Drawing
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -1.0f, -4.5f);        // move 5 units INTO the screen
    gl.glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);
                                            // otherwise it will be too large
    square.draw(gl);                        // Draw the triangle

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);


    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Load the texture for the square
    square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

    //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 

}
```

}

I think the main problem is in my open gl code. because when I run the app on real devices the camera view gets displayed for a short time until the open gl object overlays on it. Anyhow I put both classes. In AndroidManifest I chose API 7 as the minimum SDK and both the CAMERA permission and camera hardware feature is added

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I found the answer. I added these lines:

```
setContentView( glView  , new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
addContentView( cv, new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );
 glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```